# access Mongo replicaset through meteor using username and password

Tags: meteor

I am using mongo replicaset through my meteor app.

Here is my connection string and code:

```
var collectionsDB = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://usr:pwd@10.9.111.111:27017,user:pwd@10.9.111.112:27017,use:pwd@10.9.111.113:27017/myDB?replicaSet=myRelicaset&authSource=myDB&readPreference=primaryPreferred&w=1");
coll = new Mongo.Collection('<myCollection>',{ _driver:collectionsDB });
```

Problem:
When I am trying to insert to mongoDB, it tries to insert into Admin db rather myDB. The user usr has readwrite permission for myDB. I fail to understand why it is targeting Admin. As it does not have permission in Admin it through permission error.

However it works fine for individual mongo server without replicaset.

Any thing I am missing in connection string?

thanks
Nihar

Comment: did you try using the MONGO_URL environment variable instead of the MongoInternals calls? That's how I define my external URL

Comment: The issue is resolved. It was I was passing the username and password multiple times, It has to be passed once only. That fixed the issue.